# Why doesn't my Chrome extension work on other computers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Javascript-heavy (the only reason I mention this is because I think it may be part of the problem) Google Chrome extension that adds an icon to the Facebook header, and it works just fine on my computer when I load it in unpacked. But when I try to put it on another computer to test it, packed or unpacked, the Javascript simply doesn't work.

I do have a browser action icon, and that shows up fine on other computers, but it only seems to be the Javascript.

There is way too much code to post, so I'll only post my background page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
if(changeInfo.status == "complete"){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "jquery-1.6.2.min.js"});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "modify3.js"});
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tabId, {file: "modify.css"});
}
});
</script>
```

Is there any specific fix to this problem? Have others experienced it?

Comment: you need to remove the facebook tag here - there is no facebook related question here...

Comment: @Lix: Edited. I included that tag because I think it could also be part of the problem.

Comment: Is there anything in the console?

Comment: @Eric: Nothing in the console (I tested it on two separate computers).

Comment: Can you be more specific about what isn't working? Is the extension getting enabled? Does a simple alert from a background page work? Is the onUpdated listener firing as expected? Is your script getting executed? etc. Step through each section of extension and see where it stops working.

Comment: Please step through each section of extension and see where it stops working.